# Installing and configuring nginx in my production environment

Tags: nginx, php

I know there are dupes of this out there, but I can't seem to solve this in my situation.
I am installing and configuring nginx to have a useful and faster server for my VPS. I am using Putty command prompt. I am trying to create my own structure for this project. Why is nginx.conf syntax not okay? and why is this nginx.conf test unsuccessful is what I cannot understand. Could anyone provide some feedback?

And I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:18
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

The configuration details are as follows:

```
# You may add here your
server {
        server_name 123.456.789.0;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

### of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.##

server {
       listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/RESTfulAPI;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                  # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
```

Comment: Try removing `#` on line 5 and see what happens (assuming you are wanting the first `server` block in your configuration).

Comment: Also, this configuration is incomplete. There is no configuration or closing bracket for the last `location` block and no closing bracket for the `server` block it is in.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're missing some comments (`#`) on the first few lines.

Change:

```
# You may add here your
server {
        server_name 123.456.789.0;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file
```

to

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#        server_name 123.456.789.0;
#        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from your error :

> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:18

The issue seem to be situated at the first `server` directive on the top of your configuration file.

I find that there is one closing curly braces which you have commented:

```
# You may add here your
server {
        server_name 123.456.789.0;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file
```

You might want to comment the following block completely or remove the extra comment tag at the end of the `server` curly-braces.